# How to resolve path of a static file in Java?

Tags: java, jar

How can I find path of a xml (static myXml.xml) file that is embedded into jar? Obviously not by absolute path but I am facing same kind of problem with relative paths. I cannot get it relative to home folder as Java returns different home folder depending upon from where I am calling the accessing Java class. For instance, from:

- command prompt
- App server
- Eclipse launcher
- Eclipse remote debugger etc

Is there someway that my accessing class (packed in same jar) may access embedded xml regardless of where jar file exists and who is trying to access it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to do is use the class loader to load the file:

```
InputStream stream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().
                                              getResourceAsStream("myXml.xml");
```

The above code assumes that the file is at the top level of your jar.

Comment: And for static class MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("myXml.xml"). It works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the getResource and getResourceAsStream methods in the Class class? Usually those are what I have to resort to in these situations.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ClassLoader#getResource(..)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) to get InputStream of a file from the classpath:

```
Object.class.getClassLoader().getResource().openStream()
```

Also there are some other methods in ClassLoader which could be useful in your case.